# WebRTC in saved webpage

Tags: firefox

I set a fake http proxy to Firefox to ensure the saved webpage is unable to connect to the internet, but is it able to create a WebRTC connection that can also connect to the internet? How to check locally if the saved webpage has WebRTC connection by viewing page source or?

Comment: Why focus on WebRTC? It could also load pictures or scripts from external sources.

Comment: Yes, that's why I set an useless proxy to Firefox.